# Insert a json inside a json column

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a database table named `users` and it has a column named `user-json`. I have the `user-json` to store more information about my users. The boiler-plate of the `user-json` looks like this:

```
{
"id":1,
"friends":[],
"posts":[],
"messages":[],
"notifications":[],
"pin":""
}
```

Now, I have to insert or `update` the json in the notifications. I have the new json to be inserted inside it that looks like this:

```
{
"title": "A user commented on your photo",
"user_id": 1,
"post_id": 3,
"comment_id": 13
}
```

Then I will display that with some `css` as a notification in the user's dashboard. I have plans on how to do that but I am unable to insert it into the column. So, How am I supposed to do that? Thank You!

Comment: No code? No errors? I guess you'd insert it like any other field in (guessing) MySql.

Comment: Have you tried to stringify and insert it as a string? `JSON.stringify(jsonObject)`

Comment: Why do you do insert JSON in your database instead of putting normal data in your database? Historically it has always been the best approach to normalize your database as soon as possible. See: https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php Most introductions to normalization might seem a very formal, but it is not as complicated as it first seems. I've notice three mistakes all beginners make: allowing SQL-injection, not normalizing, and using deprecated mysql extension.

Answer (score 0):

Well after retrieving the data you can just push it to the notifications array and update the existing data in your table

```js
const jsonData = {
"id":1,
"friends":[],
"posts":[],
"messages":[],
"notifications":[],
"pin":""
}

const notification = {
"title": "A user commented on your photo",
"user_id": 1,
"post_id": 3,
"comment_id": 13
}

jsonData.notifications.push(notification);

console.log(jsonData);

// Update field of jsonData in mysql
```

Comment: I am doing the stuff in php page and it didn't work.The page didn't allow me to use ?> and <script> tag. I am using Laravel by the way!

Answer (score 0):

```
//get your data in your column user-json, then convert to JSON obj
//........
// data is a String
var user = JSON.parse(data);

//your have a notification obj like this
var notification = {
   "title": "A user commented on your photo",
   "user_id": 1,
   "post_id": 3,
   "comment_id": 13
};

//add notification
user.notifications.push(notification);

 // update this user in your database
 var userUpdate = JSON.stringify(user);

 //......update
```

Comment: I am doing that mysql stuff in the controller(I am using Laravel by the way) and the .php extension doesn't allow me to start <script> tags there. So, can't I do the same thing using php?

Answer (score 0):

JSON isn't supported by ANSI SQL so the way you modify JSON will depend on what type of database server you are using. If you are using a new enough version of MySQL than the following database query will append an entry into the notifications property for the object with id 1, if the `user-json` field was properly setup as a JSON field type.

```
UPDATE `users` 
   SET `user-json`=
       JSON_SET(
            `user-json`,
            '$.notifications',
            JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE(
                JSON_EXTRACT(`user-json`,'$.notifications'),
                '{
                  "title": "A user commented on your photo",
                  "user_id": 1,
                  "post_id": 3,
                  "comment_id": 13
                 }'))  
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(`user-json`,'$.id')=1
```

The entry appended is the one defined in the question.

```
{
    "title": "A user commented on your photo",
    "user_id": 1,
    "post_id": 3,
    "comment_id": 13
}
```

The MySQL Reference manual has more information about working with JSON.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html

The PHP manual has the information you need to write the code in PHP to insert your data as a prepared statement.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php